# Haskell: Preferred linux distro for web development

Tags: web-applications, haskell, hosting, yesod

Is there a preferred linux distribution for Haskell development on the web? In particular, I am doing a lot of Yesod development locally, however my web server is running RHEL (CentOS 5.8 i686) and it has not been the most seamless experience. *This is not a question related to that*, however, I am wondering if there is a distribution (and/or hosting provider) which is canonical for having good Haskell support, or has worked well from your own experience.

Comment: RHEL-based stuff tends to be a nightmare, IME :)

Answer (score 5):

Most common distros should be fine. Debian has a nice, comprehensive set of modules that work well for secure server environments.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overlook Gentoo and its Haskell overlay.

Gentoo is a source distro. You have to be willing to spend some time configuring and compiling. As to the first point, the "genkernel" utility mitigates the cost (in time) and trouble. Multi-core processors mitigate impact of the second.

The Haskell overlay is a way of supplementing the standard distro. (Overlays are widely used in a variety of connections. The Haskell overlay is just one of them.) It is expertly and assiduously maintained by experts in Haskell and Gentoo. (No, I am not a paid spokesman.) It gives you access to a great many Hackage packages seamlessly integrated into the Gentoo source tree, and it includes a utility ("hackport") that allows you to do the same for yourself if something of interest to you in Hackage is not available through standard Gentoo or the Haskell overlay.

edit: #gentoo-haskell on freenode is a good source for detailed information and guidance

Answer (score 2):

There is not a canonical distribution for Haskell development. Most distributions provide Haskell packages, but these are usually out-of-date. Many Haskell developers install the distro packages only for GHC and cabal-install, and then just use cabal-install or cabal-dev for installing additional packages, since these are more likely to be up-to-date. It's really up to you, though, both regarding the distro and how you manage your Haskell libraries and applications.